# Ionic Storage, how to stay simple in the Promise scope

Tags: angularjs, typescript, promise, ionic2

I am using Ionic Storage, and it returns a Promise...which is really impractical.

I need to get a value from Storage and depending on its boolean value, do something.

That was the code I had in Angular 1:

```
$scope.isUser = UserService.getUser() ? true : false;
$scope.isUserTemp = storageService.get("userTemp") ? true : false;
$scope.data.showLoginClose = ($scope.isUser || $scope.isUserTemp || !$rootScope.isMobile );
```

Here's the new code in typescript:

```
    let isUser: boolean;
    let isUserTemp: boolean;
    this.storage.ready().then(() => {
        this.storage.get('userTemp').then((val) => {
            isUserTemp = true ;
            isUser = UserService.getUser() ? true : false;
            this.data.showLoginClose = (isUser || userTemp || !this.isCordova.f() );
        })
        .catch( (e) => {
            isUserTemp = false ;
            isUser = UserService.getUser() ? true : false;
            this.data.showLoginClose = (isUser || userTemp || !this.isCordova.f() );
        })
    });
```

3 lines vs 14 lines, that's not an improvement.

Can you help me write something clean in the Promise scope for Angular2 / typescript, for all the cases (isUser true, userTemp : true   ; isUser false, userTemp : true  ; etc...) ?

Comment: $scope does not exist in angular 2.. it is angular 1 concept..can you add your class?

Comment: edited. that was my old code to migrate

Comment: @suraj sorry I rewrote my question, it was not clear.

Comment: You're referencing a variable called `userTemp` which doesn't seem to be initialized anywhere. Did you mean `isUserTemp`? If you did, then `this.data.showLoginClose = (isUser || userTemp || !this.isCordova.f() );` in the `then` is pointless because the result will always be true.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Based on @VinceOPS, but with fixed logic, because Ionic Storage is based on localForage, `.then()` is executed even if the variable you looking for is not present in Storage, and in this case ̀`val` is `null`.

```
    let that = this;
    this.storage.ready().then(() => {
        return this.storage.get('userTemp');
    })
    .then(retrieved => updateLoginClose(retrieved))
    .catch(e =>  console.error('ERROR: could not read Storage, error:', e));
    function updateLoginClose(retrieved) {
       let isUserTemp:boolean;
       if (retrieved !== null) {
          isUserTemp = true;
       } else {
          isUserTemp = false;
       }
       that.data.showLoginClose = isUserTemp || that.UserService.getUser() || !that.isCordova.f();
    }
```

Comment: This is no "fixed logic" but wrong coding and way too many lines of code.
See http://stackoverflow.com/questions/43182646/ionic-storage-how-to-stay-simple-in-the-promise-scope/43183339#comment73477720_43183339

Answer (score 0):

After removing useless variables `isUserTemp` (which is just set to `true` or `false`, meaning that you don't need to involve it in a condition, as you already know its value...) and `isUser` (which only depends on `UserService.getUser()`), here's what you get:

```
this.storage.ready().then(() => {
    return this.storage.get('userTemp');
}).then((val) => {
    this.data.showLoginClose = (UserService.getUser() || !this.isCordova.f() );
}).catch( (e) => {
    this.data.showLoginClose = (UserService.getUser() || !this.isCordova.f() );
});
```

I feel like something is wrong in the logic.
After a minor refactoring, you may have something like:

```
function updateLoginClose(isUserTemp: boolean) {
    this.data.showLoginClose = isUserTemp || UserService.getUser() || !this.isCordova.f();
}

this.storage.ready().then(() => {
    return this.storage.get('userTemp');
})
.then(val => updateLoginClose(!!val))
.catch(() => updateLoginClose(false));
```

Please mind that you should do something with variables `val`and `e`,  otherwise, don't declare them.

EDIT - Take `val` into account.

Comment: will "this" work in `function updateLoginClose(...` ?

Comment: @Louis in a typescript [class](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/classes.html) member function.. yes

Comment: yes I see, so what @VinceOPS wrote is not typescript, is it ?  And how to remove the declaration of vars `val` and `e` please ?

Comment: You wrote typescript, I gave a typescript answer! Doesn't it work? Please consider upvoting if the answer helped you ;). Thanks

Comment: To remove the declaration of `val` and `e`, just use an empty arrow function: `() => update...`

Comment: Thanks @VinceOPS.
Actually, your code doesn't work as expected because ionic Storage is based on localForage, and the Promise always returns, event if the value is not there, so in your code, the `.then()` is executed if the variable is not present in Storage and `val` is `null`.  So updateLoginClose(true) is always run